# How do I execute the procedure in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I created the simplest procedure in Oracle Apex, but it failed when I used the exec statement to execute.
How can I execute the procedure in Oracle Apex ?

This is my procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE hello_world
AS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');
END;
/
```

I found in other StackOverflow workarounds, I can call it like this in the  Apex > SQL Workshop > SQL Commands:

```
BEGIN

 hello_world;

 END;
```

But I want to call it like `exec hello_world` statement in Oracle Apex to get the result, is there a way? What menu or screen should I execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` (which is, actually, abbreviated `execute`) ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6)) is a **SQL*Plus** command.

`exec` *embeds* PL/SQL statement into `begin-end` block so that it could be executed.

It works in some other environments as well, such as Oracle SQL Developer or TOAD, but it **does not work in Oracle Application Express** (Apex).

Therefore, the answer to your

> I want to call it like `exec hello_world` statement in Oracle Apex to get the result, is there a way?

is **no**.